# How to combine multiple small C programs together?

Tags: c, shell, unix

One of the unix philosophies is to write small software components and then connect them together, like uzbl or git forexample, but I ask how do you combine them together to make one big application? If I were interested in gluing C programs together, do I write another program that calles them with the system() call to execute the system to give the desired behavour? What are the good practices? Where do I look for more indepth detail in this area.

For example, I'm trying to develope a program of my own and would like to compartmentalize the different components of the program together. The web browser Uzbl or version controlling software git for example, how do they bind the different binaries together to make one?

Comment: Are you actually trying to glue PROGRAMS together, or a number of FUNCTIONS together? Usually C programs are constructed by LINKING a number of functions together to make a program. There is a program, usually called a LINKER, that takes all the functions and links them together.

Comment: I think I might be trying to glue programs togehter, but don't necessarily want to use shell scripting to do that. Or is that what programs like git or uzbl do?

Comment: The unix philosophy is to *avoid* big applications.

Comment: Yes I understand but at some point one still has to glue some components together to make a system! Its a catch 22, but some situations you just can't do without, still was interested in what is the best way to glue components of a software together.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends on what level you're viewing this from. If you want to combine several pre-built programs at the command line, you can use a pipe like with Unix, e.g. `dir | sort`.

If you're developing and want to reuse existing code, you can link the existing functionality to your application as libraries, or simply reuse existing classes.

Comment: this is the answer. the unix philosophy is put small programs working together through the pipeline - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix)

Comment: link incomplete, please edit.

Answer (score 3):

You mentioned git, which is known for originally being a collection of small tools each performing a relatively small operation on the repository, and a set of scripts (shell and Perl) that use the tools. For example, you can take a look at the code of [git pull](http://repo.or.cz/w/git.git/blob/HEAD:/git-pull.sh) (which is actually a shell script) and see how it calls different git programs that most git users don't know about.

Generally, if you want to write a part of your program as a filter, let it simply read the input from stdin (using fread, fgets, fscanf, etc) and write the output to stdout (fprintf, fwrite, etc). Then you can call your filter in a shell script using the pipe.

Another way of combining programs is via bidirectional interprocess communication, that is, not via pipe in a shell script but using e.g. sockets. You can split the program to two parts, a server and a client, which communicate with each other but have separate objectives. For example the X system and FreeCiv are written this way.

There are programs which aren't easily decomposable to multiple smaller programs and filters. In that case, it's usually best to decompose the program to libraries, which is also part of Unix philosophy as the libraries can also be reused by other programs.

I'd also recommend looking at [The Art of Unix Programming](http://www.faqs.org/docs/artu/), which goes into more detail on software engineering and the Unix philosophy.